# How can I close a jQuery UI dialog after a x seconds?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I programmatically close a jQuery UI dialog after some number of seconds?

I figure I need to do something inside

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    //Something here....
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `$('#idOfYourDialogue').dialog("close");`

and see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Answer (score 4):

```
var xSeconds = 2; // 2 seconds
var myDialog = $('dialog_element').dialog('open');
setTimeout(function() { myDialog.dialog('close'); }, xSeconds * 1000);
```

Comment: For what ever reason that didn't wok for me.  I went with this instead: $(function() {
   $("#dialog").dialog();
  });
  window.setTimeout(function() {
   $('#dialog').dialog("close");
  }, 5000);